# "By night", "during night", "at day"… which propositions and articles should be used?

Tags: prepositions, articles, time

1. We travelled by night and rested by day.
2. We travelled during night and rested during day.
3. We travelled during the night and rested during the day.
4. We travelled at night and rested at day.

#1 is correct. It is from a dictionary. According to the Cambridge dictionary, 'by' means 'during'. Then, can we use #2? What about #3 and #4?

Comment: Can you add a link to or quote the Cambridge definition you are referring to? *by* has 20 or more definitions by most dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

2 and 4 are not correct as *during night* and *during day* are not corret in English as they require an article.

The 3rd one is correct but not as natural as the first one. You want to try and say your sentence in a compact way as possible like the first one.

Comment: 2 and 4 are not correct. "During night", "during day" and "at day" are not correct English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey edited